# run Xcode project tests from terminal

Tags: xcode

I am quite curious to know if there is a way to achieve the same that you get, when in Xcode you press cmd-u (or select Test from the menu).

I am writing some UI tests for an application, and would love to automate the whole thing.

So far, any attempt to automate via applescript has been quite unsuccessful (I told myself how hard it is to simulate 2 button pressed...); so I thought that maybe there is a proper way to just run the command line commands and have the simulator to pop and run the tests, like it does in Xcode.

Altho if this function was known, I would find something online, but it seems that there is no way to simulate the test command via console.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the xcodebuild command?

The man page says:

> buildaction ...
>        Specify a build action (or actions) to perform on the target. Available build actions are:
>
> ```
>  test   Test a scheme from the build root (SYMROOT).  This requires specifying a scheme.
> ```

So, perhaps that will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that (which is the only command that would do what xcode does, in a terminal window), but it requires you to change the project and create a scheme. I will give it a try, but it sounds strange that I have to create a scheme, while in Xcode I just push the test button.

Comment: Schemes are a standard part of the Xcode workflow. I might suggest checking out the WWDC 2011 Mastering Schemes in Xcode 4 video ( https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/ ).